# Ember.js is rendering a div from one template on different routes

Tags: jquery, html, model-view-controller, ember.js

I've encountered a problem when creating a website using Ember.js.

I'm using [Ember-tools](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-tools) when creating my Ember-projects.

I have these templates:

1. index.hbs
2. food.hbs
3. application.hbs

**application.hbs**

```
{{partial header}}
{{outlet}}
{{partial footer}}
```

When I'm browsing on my `indexRoute` and clicks a link to the `foodRoute` everything looks fine, but when I'm clicking a link to `indexRoute` from `foodRoute`, I get HTML from my `food.hbs` at the bottom of the page. 
The more I navigate between these routes, the more clones of my `<div class="hero"></div>` renders, on both routes!

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have bad html in one of your templates.  Likely a missing closing tag or something along those lines.  You'll need to show your templates for anything more than that.

Comment: Saw that I was missing a closing ``div`` .. Cheers